# How to check the radio button in RadioGroup in ListView Android

Tags: java, android

I am developing a apps for quiz. There are ten questions, each with four answers A, B, C, D and represented RadioGroup and the end is submit button. The list of questions is represented by one ListView. The user selects the answer, then they click submit button. I have a question: How to check the answers in turn in ListView ? Please help me. Thanks so much!

this is the code of questions custom:

```
public class mAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Question> {
    Activity context;
    int resource;
    List<Question> objects;

    public mAdapter(Activity context, int resource, List<Question> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.objects = objects;
        this.resource = resource;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = this.context.getLayoutInflater();
        View row = inflater.inflate(this.resource, null);

        final Question question = this.objects.get(position);

        RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) row.findViewById(R.id.btnGroup);
        TextView txtID = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtID);
        TextView txtContent = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtContent);
        RadioButton btnA = (RadioButton) row.findViewById(R.id.btnA);
        RadioButton btnB = (RadioButton) row.findViewById(R.id.btnB);
        RadioButton btnC = (RadioButton) row.findViewById(R.id.btnC);
        RadioButton btnD = (RadioButton) row.findViewById(R.id.btnD);

        txtID.setText((position + 1) + "");
        txtContent.setText(question.getContent());
        btnA.setText(question.getOptionA());
        btnB.setText(question.getOptionB());
        btnC.setText(question.getOptionC());
        btnD.setText(question.getOptionD());

        return row;
    }

}
```

This is the code that pushes the question into listView

```
lvQuestion= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvQuestion);
testAdapter = new mAdapter(this, R.layout.custom_lisview, listQuestion);
lvQuestion.setAdapter(testAdapter);

btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {

       }
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

To handle `radioButton` in `listView`

```
btnA.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

if (isChecked)
      btnA.setText(question.getOptionA());
     }
 });

btnB.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

if (isChecked)
     btnB.setText(question.getOptionB());
       }
});

// others code
```

To get the answer by `OnClick`

```
btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
     final int child=listView.getChildCount();
      for(int i=0;i<child;i++) {
        if(listView.childAt(i) instanceof RadioGroup){
         RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) row.findViewById(R.id.btnGroup);
         rg=(RadioGroup)listView.childAt(i);
         int a = rg.getChildCount();
         for(int j=0;j<a;++j) {
            if((RadioButton)rg.getChildAt(j).isChecked()==true) {
           System.out.println("RadioButton At "+j+" Is Selected");}
          }
       }
  }
}
});
```